# The best way of PHP Caching

Tags: php, mysql, caching

Currently, I am trying to write a software about ecommerce. My data is usually just MySQL queries. For instance language variable results (**err_no_cat** => `No category found`)

Which way is the best and simple method to cache like these data in PHP?

Comment: There is no "best way".  If there was, everyone would do it.  Instead, the methods are dependent upon the implementation.  So if you would like advice, it'd be best to describe your implementation...

Comment: why do you need to cache that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

memcache is a pretty common solution.  Facebook and some other big names use it.  It can be very fast.

http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcache.php

Comment: Facebook don't use it no more, there sources codes run in a C++ compiler but im sure they did.

Comment: @RobertPitt ROTFLMAO, you made my day

Comment: @OneOfOne its damn different things! hiphop is a compiler for the CODE, but memcaced is used to store DATA. Any chance for you to understand the difference?

Comment: I know about hip-hop, I may have been mistaken about Memcache :/

Answer (score 6):

[apc](http://www.scribd.com/doc/88689/ApcFacebook)

Answer (score 4):

use APC if your app is using single server - you can use it as opcode and regular key=>value cache.

use memcached only if you have multiple servers and you need cache to be available to all of them - that's the point of distributed cache.

Remember that APC is about **6 times faster** then memcached.