# PHP cache system

Tags: php, caching

I am wondering if some one knows good sites where I can find useful information in regards to PHP based cache systems and how to make one. Since I want to reduce the stress on MySQL which is being called every 60 sec via jQuery AJAX function.

Comment: possible duplicate of [The best way of PHP Caching](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502597/the-best-way-of-php-caching)

Answer (score 1):

- You can use [MP_Cache](https://bitbucket.org/jschreuder/mp_cache/downloads) for simple php based caching needs.
- If you are looking for a distributed caching solution then consider memcached. PHP has nice integration with memcache as described here: http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcache.php
- [Alternative PHP cache](https://bitbucket.org/jschreuder/mp_cache/downloads) is another option you may consider.

Answer (score 0):

well ajax / jquery is immense at bandwidth usage, you can cache the results

look here for example: http://blog.digitalstruct.com/2008/02/27/php-performance-series-caching-techniques/

but you cant reduce so much the bandwidth usage of jquery
but you can trim down the size of the websites, scripts and also the database (better database scheme)

Comment: so would it be much better to drop ajax? and just use iframes with meta refresh or js refresh instead?

Comment: thats even worse  iframes are a gruel   no but you should look that your hoster accepts your ajax app (many dont like ajax apps with high bandwith usage like chats on their server - read the rules) and also look that the pages thatare small are delivered through the server so the bandwidth usage is smaller, and the timeout for your ajax app should not be too small

well memcache is also good and often helps a lot =)

Comment: actually this is a CMS ^^ that I am building to be used. The only AJAX that there is atm is ability to change pages by clicking truth the navigation without page refresh so jQuery makes a call to the server for the file it needs to load for what ever. And other then that there is Notice which are updated every 60sec and Notice viewer which fetches note truth AJAX call to PHP so thats about it no chats as the eye can see and never will be since I don't like them that much.

Comment: well if you have no problems with it and your hoster also it can stay so

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use Super Cache, which is a file cache mechanism which won't use `json_encode` or `serialize`. It is simple to use and really fast compared to other PHP Cache mechanism.

Simple PHP cache mechanism which is 500X Faster Caching than Redis/Memcache/APC in PHP & HHVM
https://packagist.org/packages/smart-php/super-cache

Ex:

```
<?php
require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';
use SuperCache\SuperCache as sCache;

//Saving cache value with a key
// sCache::cache('<key>')->set('<value>');
sCache::cache('myKey')->set('Key_value');

//Retrieving cache value with a key
echo sCache::cache('myKey')->get();
?>
```