# Where to store info besides mysql

Tags: mysql

My php script pulls about 1000 names from the mysql db on a certain page. These names are used for a javascript autocomplete script.

I think there's a better method to do this. I would like to update the names with a cronjob once a day (php) and store the names locally in a text file? Where else can I store it? It's not sensitive info.

It should be readable and writable to php.

Comment: It's hard to give any suggestions about what would be "better" without knowing what sort of "better" you're looking for. What don't you like about your MySQL solution? Why do you think a text file would be better?

Comment: @JonSkeet I have had problems with mysql utilizing 100% of the ram on my server before, so I thought this could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you only need the data updated once a day, have a cron-script generate a static json file in some fixed location. Then read this with ajax on the client and make sure it caches it on the client.

Or potentially, generate the file whenever the database is updated (if this is applicable, I don't know your application)

Answer (score 1):

It's unlikely reading from a text file will be much faster than a database query - MySQL already does a lot of caching that should make your query speedy.

If you need to make this query often and performance is a problem often you could consider using a caching module for PHP.

**Related**

- [The best way of PHP Caching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502597/the-best-way-of-php-caching)

Answer (score 1):

You could try Memcache. But that could be like using a sledge-hammer to crack a nut.

*Edit* What about storing the data as simple file and let users (JavaScript) download it. Clients would not query the server for every key stroke because they could search for matching values themself. Format could be JSON because it is simple and JavaScript native.